# "One of (the) students in the school is going to study abroad." - should I add "the"?

Tags: grammar, structure

Does the expression "one of..." have to be followed by "the, my, your, etc."?

Can I say?

> "One of students in the school is going to study abroad."

Or it is better to say,

> "One of the students in the school is going to study abroad."

Comment: If you start with ***One of***, you *must* include ***the***, so (1) above is syntactically invalid. Alternatively, you could discard ***of*** - there's nothing wrong with (3) *One student in the school is...* - or just (4) *A student in the school...*. Note that ***one*** would often carry heavy stress in (3) - strongly implying that it's "unusual, remarkable" that *even one* student should have managed to do this.

Comment: @FumbleFingers A possessive adjective or number could be used in place of "the". Also I don't agree about the heavy stress. That is a possible use pattern, but not, I think, an overwhelmingly common one.

Comment: @DavidSiegel: In general, and definitely in the context of my previous comment, ***one*** is an "emphatic" alternative to ***a / an***.

Comment: @FumbleFingers "One of my students is going to study abroad; twenty are taking honors classes; eight are doing internships" or "One of my students is going to study abroad; three did last year" or "One of my students is going to study abroad; I had expected more".  One may be just a count, not an emphasis, and is IME interchangeable with "a/an" with no extra emphasis implied when no other counts are given.

Comment: @DavidSiegel: You're changing the context. I'm talking about the difference between ***One** student in the school [even] won a scholarship to Oxford* and the same with ***A** student*. You can't casually switch between ***one*** and ***a*** with "of my students".

Answer (score 1):

### No, one cannot just omit "the" here

In the construction

> One of {group} {form of 'to Be'}

the specification of the group should start with either a determiner, or a possessive adjective, or possibly some other word such as a number which will serve the same function:

> - One of the students in the school is going to study abroad. [image: Green check-mark, indicating acceptable form]
> - One of my students is going to study abroad. [image: Green check-mark, indicating acceptable form]
> - One of six students is going to study abroad.  [image: Green check-mark, indicating acceptable form] [*"Six" functions as a determiner in this construction.*]
> - One of the third year students is going to study abroad. [image: Green check-mark, indicating acceptable form]
> - One of our friends is going to join the club. [image: Green check-mark, indicating acceptable form]

But one cannot simply omit the determiner so :

> One of students in the school is going to study abroad. [image: Red X, indicating incorrect form]

is not correct.